# Automatically Accept meeting invite for user using MS Graph

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to accept the meeting using Service Principal who has Admin Consent on Calendar.Read, Calendar.ReadWrite permission using MS Graph, so that the invited user doesn't have to accept the meeting. But i keep getting object was not found error.

**High Level code:**

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    string resultjson = "";
    string eventId = "Aaakndf8ianffnddd=";
    string attendeeUPN = "john@test.com";  //user who has the meeting event
    string authToken = GetToken();  //accessToken is generated using servicePrincipal which has Admin Consent on Calendar.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite permissions both on Delegated and Application Type
    
    EventAcceptRequestBody eventAcceptRequestBody = new EventAcceptRequestBody();
    eventAcceptRequestBody.SendResponse = false;    
    string jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventAcceptRequestBody);
    
    string url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{attendeeUPN}/calendar/events/{eventId}/accept"
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
    var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");   
    
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
    resultjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return resultjson;
}
```

**Error:**
{"error":{"code":"ErrorItemNotFound","message":"The specified object was not found in the store."}}

Does anyone know why i keep getting above error?
Thanks

Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

can you try making the same request, or try to GET the event via the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)? That will help confirm that the event exists and the ID is correct. AFAIK, if you are getting a 404, the API call worked fine but an event with that ID does not exist.

Comment: the event does exists, i tried that in graph explorer too. I didn't include in the above code but first i make rest api call to create the event, and grab the eventId and make the 'accept' call to accept the meeting, so i do know the event does exist.